# Object.create(Object.prototype);とObject.create({});の違い

Tags: javascript

下記違いは何でしょうか？

```
Object.create(Object.prototype);

Object.create({});
```

・上 … null をプロトタイプとするオブジェクト
・下 … 上 をプロトタイプとするオブジェクト？

・それぞれメリットデメリットがあれば知りたいです

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どちらも実質的には同じですので、メリットデメリットといったものはありません。

厳密には、下の`Object.create({});`は以下のコードと等価です。

```
Object.create(Object.create(Object.prototype));
```

内部的にはプロトタイプチェーンの階層が異なります。

つまり、`Object.create(Object.prototype);`は直接の`prototype`が`Object.prototype`であるオブジェクトを生成しますが、`Object.create({});`の場合は直接の`prototype`は`{}`によって生成されたオブジェクトになります。その`{}`によって生成されたオブジェクトの`prototype`は`Object.prototype`です。

```
a = {};

b = Object.create(Object.prototype);
a.isPrototypeOf(b);                  // false
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(b);   // true

b = Object.create(a);
a.isPrototypeOf(b);                  // true
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(b);   // true
```